# Set a pointer to an empty interface

Tags: go, openapi-generator

We are using the [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate a [go-gin-server](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/go-gin-server).  This generates models containing properties of type `*interface{}` eg.

```
type Material struct {
    Id *interface{} `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Reference *interface{} `json:"reference,omitempty"`
}
```

If I have an instance of this struct, with nil pointers, how can these be set? I have tried the following:

```
theReturnId := "abc123"
material.Id = &theReturnId
```

This gives a compilation error of:

> cannot use &theReturnId (value of type *string) as *interface{} value in assignment: *string does not implement *interface{} (type *interface{} is pointer to interface, not interface)*

```
theReturnId := "abc123"
*material.Id = theReturnId
```

This gives a runtime error that the pointer is nil.

I have tried a bunch of other things but to no avail.  What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost never need a pointer to an interface. You should be passing interfaces as values, but the underlying data though can still be a pointer.

You need to reconsider your design/code generation technique to not use such an approach as it is not idiomatic Go.

---

If you still want to use it, use a typed `interface{}` variable and take its address. The way you are doing in your example is incorrect as `theReturnId` is a string type taking its address would mean `*string` type, which cannot be assigned to `*interface{}` type directly as Go is a strongly typed language

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Material struct {
    Id        *interface{} `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Reference *interface{} `json:"reference,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    newMaterial := Material{}
    var foobar interface{} = "foobar"
    newMaterial.Id = &foobar
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", newMaterial.Id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Inian.  We're a bit stuck with the code generator we're using.  I'm not sure why it generates every field as *interface{} as everything is typed in our openapi definition.  It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> theReturnId := "abc123"
> *material.Id = theReturnId
> ```
>
> This gives a runtime error that the pointer is nil.

Because the field `Id` is set to its *zero value*, i.e.: `nil`, and dereferencing it (`*material.Id`) results in a run-time error. You can write a constructor for `Material` that initializes its `*interface{}` fields:

```
func NewMaterial() Material {
    return Material {
        new(interface{}),
        new(interface{}),
    }
}
```

Now, you can safely dereference the field `Id`:

```
material := NewMaterial()
theReturnId := "abc123"
*material.Id = theReturnId
```